# mysql Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1267

When I execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM login_table
WHERE username = 'sam'
  AND pass = AES_ENCRYPT('passabc', 'mystring')
```

I keep on getting this error.

> #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

expicetly cast to the correct collation.
google your error - there are too many descriptions out there what to do!

or change your password-field from the table to the same collation as the result from AES_ENCRYPT returns (phpMyAdmin might be useful)

Comment: I have got this solution for adding _latin1 infront of 'sam
'SELECT * FROM login_table
WHERE username = _latin1'sam'
  AND pass = AES_ENCRYPT('passabc', 'mystring') 

but cant use _latin1 for pass field

how to change the collation of password fiel?

Comment: just google'd "mysql change collation column"...
first result: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html where it describes: ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DATATYPE CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_your_collation

Comment: I changed the collation from "latin1_swedish_ci" to "utf8_general_ci" for the description field(varchar). & it worked thanks

other way around is select * from content where desc like _latin1'%text%'